# function that set pin high for defined number of times and time

Tags: c++, arduino, nested-loops

I have this problem where I try to set an output pin high for a set time and times.

I do the call with `hapticFeedback(1000, 2, 1);`

the variables are defined as

```
unsigned long hapticPreviousMillis = 0;
int hapticState = LOW;
int oneshotHaptic = 0;
```

here is the function. For some reason I only get the pin set HIGH and not the blinks and LOW

```
void hapticFeedback(int activeLength, int repeats, int oneshotHaptic) {  

    if (oneshotHaptic == 1) {

        for (int x = 0; x <= repeats; x++) {

           unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

           if (currentMillis - hapticPreviousMillis >= (unsigned long)activeLength) {

                hapticPreviousMillis = currentMillis;


                if (hapticState == LOW) {
                    hapticState = HIGH;
                }
                else {
                    hapticState = LOW;
                }

                digitalWrite(haptic, hapticState);
            }
        }

    }

    oneshotHaptic = 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask] and [example]. As is, your code has a lot of hidden parts to it, and it would be hard if not impossible for any of us to guess why your observed output does not match your expected output.

Comment: Oh, it appears that you want your function `hapticFeedback(1000, 2, 1);` to blink twice, with each blink being 1000 milliseconds? Right now your code will poll the timer twice (not blink twice), and only change the state if the last time since polling was greater than 1000 milliseconds. Your whole loop probably executes much faster than 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: thank you and yes you guessed right about my intentions :-)

Comment: The solution is to either toggle your output, calculate how long you need to sleep so it stays at that level, and then sleep for that amount of time (this is blocking, but that may be fine depending on your application). The other option is to use threads that do the same thing, but I don't know if you can thread in arduino. Or you can register some kind of callback function, but again I don't know if you can do that in arduino.

Comment: arduino can do some protothreading but thats just pseudo but perhaps a nested for-for loop. i will look in to that

Comment: You don't need to do a nested loop. it's just `loop for repeat times; toggle output; calculate sleep duration; sleep for that duration`

Comment: Inside your `hapticFeedback` routine, I think you should initialize your `hapticPreviousMillis` variable (it doesn't need to be global) with the current `millis()`. Use a `while` instead of an `if` to spin in-place until enough time has passed, then toggle your port pin.  

Actually, like @John said, just turn the pin on, do a `delay(activelength/2)`, turn it off, and do a final `delay(activelength/2)` afterwords. Put that in the existing `while` loop, and you should be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and if anyone else is looking for this here is what I came up with. It might not be the smoothest of code but it does what I intended it to do

in the loop I have

```
    if (setOneshotHaptic == 1) {

    hapticFeedback(activeLength);
}
```

and the haptic function look like this

```
void hapticFeedback(int activeLength) {  

    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

     if (currentMillis - hapticPreviousMillis >= (unsigned long)activeLength) {

         hapticPreviousMillis = currentMillis;

         if (x == repeats) {
                         setOneshotHaptic = false;
                         hapticState = HIGH;
                         x = 0;
         }

         if (hapticState == LOW) {
             hapticState = HIGH;
             x++;
         }
         else {
             hapticState = LOW;

         }

         digitalWrite(haptic, hapticState);

     }
```

}

whenever i like to have haptic feedback i can define the following vars

```
    setOneshotHaptic = true;
    repeats = 3;
    activeLength = 1000;
```

When the number of repeats has been reached I lay down the oneshot, force the output to high for it to be low by the routine and finally reset my repeat counter.

There might be nicer ways to do this. However I couldn't find them and this works for me....